# Why is $(\log n)^3\in O(\sqrt n)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Comparing the order of growth of the two functions by taking a limit and using l'hospitals rule, it seems that $\sqrt{n}$ should be O($log^3n$). Here are the steps I took:

$$\lim_{n \to ∞} \frac{(\log_{10}n)^3}{\sqrt{n}}$$

L'hospitals:
 $$=\lim_{n \to ∞} \frac{3(\log_{10}n)^2  \frac{1}{n\ln(10)}}{\frac{1}{2n^2}}$$

$$=\lim_{n \to ∞} \frac{3(\log_{10}n)^2  2n^2}{n\ln(10)}$$

$$=\lim_{n \to ∞} \frac{3(\log_{10}n)^2  2n}{\ln(10)} = ∞$$

I.e., since $(\log_{10}n)^3$ was in the numerator, and the limit goes to infinity, it has the greater order of growth.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

What went wrong is that you differentiated $\sqrt{n}$ incorrectly. The result should be $(1/2)n^{-1/2}$. Then manipulation gives you a $\log^2 n$ on top, and $\sqrt{n}$ at the bottom, and you can apply L'Hospital's Rule again, and then again.

By the way, you should take the cube root first. So you will be  looking at $\frac{\log n}{n^{1/6}}$. Then one step of L'Hospital's Rule does it. The limit is $0$.

Comment: Oh, gosh! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, I don't know what $\log$ means in your course. My default meaning is the natural logarithm, which makes the derivative simple. But the limit is $0$ whatever the base, as long as it is $\gt 1$.

Comment: The default base we're using is 10. I will update the question to include this.